# Can't pair Bluetooth devices with RTL8723be on Zesty 17.04

Tags: bluetooth, asus, 17.04, realtek

I have an Asus Vivobook with the following bluetooth hardware:

```
Realtek bluetooth usb-2.10<br>
configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

I have installed the following:

```
ii  blueman 2.0.4-1ubuntu2 Graphical bluetooth manager<br>
ii  bluez 5.43-0ubuntu1 Bluetooth tools and daemons<br>
ii  bluez-obexd 5.43-0ubuntu1 bluez obex daemon<br>
ii  bluez-tools 0.2.0~20140808-5build1 Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
```

When I use bluetoothctl to try to pair a headset, I get

```
[NEW] Controller 58:00:E3:2C:61:5B roland-asus-vivo [default]<br>
[NEW] Device 00:11:22:33:98:DD BTH-068
```

Trying to pair the BTH-068, I get:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 00:11:22:33:98:DD<br>
Attempting to pair with 00:11:22:33:98:DD<br>
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed
```

In /var/log/syslog I then see no bluetooth related events.

I have commented out this line in /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

```
[keyfile]<br>
#unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

of course, restarted services, purged and reinstalled bluetooth, bluez and some more, but nothing makes a difference.

Additionally, when I allow my Ulefone Metal Android 6 phone to be paired with, the device is not even detected...  so it's not just the headset that not being paired with.

~$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; rfkill list all; uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

`02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1723]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
Linux roland-asus-vivo 4.10.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 22 17:43:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    0.188318] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.309471] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    2.288855] usb 1-8: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   13.691653] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.691670] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.691672] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.691675] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.691680] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.084129] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   14.381969] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   14.381970] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   14.382614] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   14.382616] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   14.382619] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   14.420969] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   14.420975] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 0, total size 22496
[   14.530629] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   14.530631] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   14.530631] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   14.530632] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   14.530633] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   14.530633] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   14.530667] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   14.530684] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   14.530685] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   14.530686] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   14.530687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   22.674094] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.674095] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.674098] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   44.488376] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   44.488389] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   44.488399] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11`

Modules loaded:
~$ lsmod | grep 8723

`rtl8723be              90112  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              782336  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be`

~$ dmesg | grep -i blue

`[    2.288855] usb 1-8: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   13.691653] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.691670] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.691672] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.691675] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.691680] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.381969] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   14.381970] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   14.382614] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   14.382616] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   14.382619] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   14.420969] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   14.420975] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 0, total size 22496
[   14.530629] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   14.530631] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   14.530631] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   14.530632] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   14.530633] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   14.530633] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   14.530667] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   14.530684] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   14.530685] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   14.530686] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   14.530687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   22.674094] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.674095] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.674098] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   44.488376] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   44.488389] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   44.488399] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11`

**UPDATE:** When I plug in an external bluetooth adaptor, the devices are all easily paired, so this seems to be a driver problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: It seems https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1542426 is related.  If so, then it's a bug in the firmware, not?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [file](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/master/Linux_BT_USB_2.11.20140423_8723BE/8723B/rtl8723b_config) and copy it to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin`.

Then reboot.

Comment: I did that, restarted the machine, BT connected to and paired the headset once, but then doesn't see the device anymore on subsequent connection attempts.

Comment: Not even restarting the machine helps.  BT doesn't detect any devices.  If I make BT discoverable in Ubuntu, other devices don't find it either.

Comment: I am also facing this file. It come on wake-up and then it fails wake-up.