# Error on Wake up: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin

Tags: suspend, bluetooth

This error  `hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin`
is troubling me a lot. It fails my wake up.

Nowhere this problem is mentioned correctly which can be implemented.

```
$ journalctl -p err -e --since today | grep -i bluetooth
Jul 26 23:35:41 satya-X556UR kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
Jul 26 23:36:00 satya-X556UR bluetoothd[1635]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jul 26 23:36:00 satya-X556UR bluetoothd[1635]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul 26 23:36:00 satya-X556UR bluetoothd[1635]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul 26 23:36:00 satya-X556UR bluetoothd[1635]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

[Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286433) it suggest to download a firmware but the link is not working.

I got [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/linux-firmware) but I don't know if this is correct and how to install it.

[Here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/187) it says to uninstall a package but I don't see that package in my box.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925465/cant-pair-bluetooth-devices-with-rtl8723be-on-zesty-17-04/925478) is related but not working. My Laptop is Asus too.

Comment: This has been fixed lately in the kernel code.